# How to compare columns of two dataframes and have consequences when they match in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to have Python Pandas compare two dataframes with each other. In dataframe 1, i have two columns (AC-Cat and Origin). I am trying to compare the AC-Cat column with the inputs of Dataframe 2. If a match is found between one of the columns of Dataframe 2 and the value of dataframe 1 being studied, i want Pandas to copy the header of the column of Dataframe 2 in which the match is found to a new column in Dataframe 1.

DF1:

```
f = {'AC-Cat': pd.Series(['B737', 'A320', 'MD11']),
      'Origin': pd.Series(['AJD', 'JFK', 'LRO'])}
Flight_df = pd.DataFrame(f)
```

DF2:

```
w = {'CAT-C': pd.Series(['DC85', 'IL76', 'MD11', 'TU22', 'TU95']),
      'CAT-D': pd.Series(['A320', 'A321', 'AN12', 'B736', 'B737'])}
WCat_df = pd.DataFrame(w)
```

I imported pandas as pd and numpy as np and tried to define a function to compare these columns.

```py
def get_wake_cat(AC_cat):
    try:
        Wcat = [WCat_df.columns.values[0]][WCat_df.iloc[:,1]==AC_cat].values[0]
    except:
        Wcat = np.NAN
    return Wcat

Flight_df.loc[:,'CAT'] = Flight_df.loc[:,'AC-Cat'].apply(lambda CT: get_wake_cat(CT))
```

However, the function does not result in the desired outputs. For example: Take the B737 AC-Cat value. I want Python Pandas to then find this value in DF2 in the column CAT-D and copy this header to the new column of DF 1. This does not happen. Can someone help me find out why my code is not giving the desired results?

Comment: It is worth mentioning what do you expect to happen if ther are matches in both 'CAT-C' and 'CAT-D'. If you want two rows, than @anki_91 answer is the solution. If you want it in one row with 2 new columns, than use what I wrote.

Comment: In essence, it is not supposed to have matches in both categories (from the data side of things) however good tip for my understanding of how to program these kind of things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty but I think I got it working. Part of the error was that the function did not have WCat_df. I also changed the indexing into two steps:

```
def get_wake_cat(AC_cat, WCat_df):
    try:
        d=WCat_df[WCat_df.columns.values][WCat_df.iloc[:]==AC_cat]
        Wcat=d.columns[(d==AC_cat).any()][0]
    except:
        Wcat = np.NAN
    return Wcat
```

Then you need to change your next line to:

```
Flight_df.loc[:,'CAT'] = Flight_df.loc[:,'AC-Cat'].apply(lambda CT: get_wake_cat(CT,WCat_df ))


   AC-Cat   Origin  CAT
0   B737    AJD CAT-D
1   A320    JFK CAT-D
2   MD11    LRO CAT-C
```

Hope that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

IUC, you can do a [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
final=(Flight_df.merge(WCat_df.stack().reset_index(1,name='AC-Cat'),on='AC-Cat',how='left')
 .rename(columns={'level_1':'New'}))
print(final)
```

Or with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
final=Flight_df.merge(WCat_df.melt(var_name='New',value_name='AC-Cat'),
                                                on='AC-Cat',how='left')
```

---

```
  AC-Cat Origin    New
0   B737    AJD  CAT-D
1   A320    JFK  CAT-D
2   MD11    LRO  CAT-C
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you 2 new columns with the name\s of the match\s found:

```
Flight_df['CAT1'] = Flight_df['AC-Cat'].map(lambda x: 'CAT-C' if x in list(WCat_df['CAT-C']) else '')
Flight_df['CAT2'] = Flight_df['AC-Cat'].map(lambda x: 'CAT-D' if x in list(WCat_df['CAT-D']) else '')
Flight_df.loc[Flight_df['CAT1'] == '', 'CAT1'] = Flight_df['CAT2']
Flight_df.loc[Flight_df['CAT1'] == Flight_df['CAT2'], 'CAT2'] = ''
```